# Rails callback not using self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self

Code snippet from Rails Guides :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      before_validation :normalize_name, on: :create

      protected
        def normalize_name
          self.name = self.name.downcase.titleize
        end
    end
```

Why did we use `self.name` in the right side of the statement? Can't we say

```
self.name = name.downcase.titleize
```

Comment: Be adventurous and try it! :-)

Comment: "Why did we use self.name in the right side of the statement?" You tell us. You didn't have to, so why did you?

Comment: @meagar, this code snippet is from the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it could make code unreadable or lead to ambiguity.
It's more clear to use `self.name` on both sides so everyone reading your code knows what happens.

I've done a small example using IRB to illustrate what happens:

```
2.1.5 :014 > class User
2.1.5 :015?>   attr_accessor :name
2.1.5 :016?>   def normalize_name
2.1.5 :017?>     self.name = name.downcase
2.1.5 :018?>     end
2.1.5 :019?>   end
 => :normalize_name 
2.1.5 :020 > u = User.new
 => #<User:0x007ff81282a070> 
2.1.5 :021 > u.name = "NAME"
 => "NAME" 
2.1.5 :022 > u.normalize_name
 => "name" 
2.1.5 :023 >
```

So yes, you can do it.
But it's cleaner to use `self.name` so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: just got my pull request merged into rails where I deleted the self :) Thanks tho.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a community convention to use `self` only when using write accessors.

```
# writer
self.name=

# reader
name
```

Defined in: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required.

Example from guide:

```
# bad
def ready?
  if self.last_reviewed_at > self.last_updated_at
    self.worker.update(self.content, self.options)
    self.status = :in_progress
  end

  self.status == :verified
end

# good
def ready?
  if last_reviewed_at > last_updated_at
    worker.update(content, options)
    self.status = :in_progress
  end

  status == :verified
end
```